# Not able to push Vapor to Heroku

Tags: heroku, vapor

I made some minor changes in `Vapor` / `Swift` code. Trying to push no `Heroku`, but get an error.

```
remote: -----> Downloading curl 7.52.1        
remote: tar: This does not look like a tar archive        
remote: 
remote: gzip: stdin: not in gzip format        
remote: tar: Child returned status 1        
remote: tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now        
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile curl app.        
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed        
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to frozen-sea-46940.        
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/frozen-sea-46940.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/frozen-sea-46940.git'
Completed with errors, see above
```

[image]

I event called an `vapor update`, regenerated Xcode project but did not helped. Any idea?

---

```
Kukoda-MacBook-Pro:frozen-sea-46940 kukodajanos$ heroku buildpacks
=== frozen-sea-46940 Buildpack URLs
1. https://github.com/vzsg/heroku-buildpack-curl-http2.git
2. https://github.com/vapor-community/heroku-buildpack.git
```

Comment: Please include the output of `heroku buildpacks`.

Comment: @vzsg it is included

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Push your project to Heroku again, it will work now.

---

The issue was in the curl-http2 buildpack: the version it was trying to download no longer exists on Ubuntu's servers. I have resolved this just now.

Should you run into a similar problem in the future, *and it's not a build error in your application code*, please open an issue at the GitHub repo of the failing buildpack.